# Impossible to read gmail notification

Tags: android, notifications, gmail

I'm using the notification listener api to read notification information but it seems impossible to read the text of a Gmail notification. Here what adb says:

```
extras={
        android.title=john
        android.support.actionExtras={0=Bundle[EMPTY_PARCEL], 1=Bundle[EMPTY_PARCEL]}
        android.subText=bar@gmail.com
        android.showChronometer=false
        android.icon=2130837727
        android.text=MyText
        android.progress=0
        android.progressMax=0
        android.showWhen=true
        android.people=[Ljava.lang.String;@b1564718 {
          mailto:foo@gmail.com
        }
        android.largeIcon=android.graphics.Bitmap@b15c6130 (128x128)
        android.infoText=null
        android.wearable.EXTENSIONS=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=1200]
        android.progressIndeterminate=false
        android.scoreModified=false
      }
```

With other notification it works. Any tips? I'm reading the notification in this way:

```
String text = extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok problem solved. The information about the notification are stored as **CharSequence** so you have to get it with `getCharSequence()`. Since String implements the CharSequence interface it's possible that it works but not always. However using CharSequence it works.